# Optimizing MySQL Import (Converting a Verbose SQL Dump to a Speedy One / use extended-inserts)

Tags: mysql, import, text-processing

We are using mysqldump with the options `--complete-insert --skip-extended-insert` to create database dumps that are kept in VCS. We use these options (and the VCS) to have the possibility to easily compare different database versions.

Now importing of the dump takes quite a while because there are - of course - single inserts per database row.

Is there an easy way to convert such a verbose dump to one with a single insert per table? Does anyone maybe already have a some script at hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a little python script that converts this:

```sql
LOCK TABLES `actor` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `actor` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `actor` (`actor_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `last_update`) VALUES (1,'PENELOPE','GUINESS','2006-02-15 12:34:33');
INSERT INTO `actor` (`actor_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `last_update`) VALUES (2,'NICK','WAHLBERG','2006-02-15 12:34:33');
INSERT INTO `actor` (`actor_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `last_update`) VALUES (3,'ED','CHASE','2006-02-15 12:34:33');
```

into this:

```sql
LOCK TABLES `actor` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `actor` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `actor` VALUES(1,'PENELOPE','GUINESS','2006-02-15 12:34:33'),(2,'NICK','WAHLBERG','2006-02-15 12:34:33'),(3,'ED','CHASE','2006-02-15 12:34:33');
```

It's not very pretty or well tested, but it works on the [Sakila](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/index.html) test [database dumps](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html), so it can handle non-trivial dump files.

Anyway, here's the script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- #

import re
import sys

re_insert = re.compile(r'^insert into `(.*)` \(.*\) values (.*);', re.IGNORECASE)

current_table = ''

for line in sys.stdin:
    if line.startswith('INSERT INTO'):
        m = re_insert.match(line)
        table = m.group(1)
        values = m.group(2)

        if table != current_table:
            if current_table != '':
                sys.stdout.write(";\n\n")
            current_table = table
            sys.stdout.write('INSERT INTO `' + table + '` VALUES ' + values)
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(',' + values)
    else:
        if current_table != '':
            sys.stdout.write(";\n")
            current_table = ''
        sys.stdout.write(line)

if current_table != '':
    sys.stdout.write(';')
```

It expects piped input on stdin and prints to stdout. If you saved the script as `mysqldump-convert.py`, you'd use it like this:

```
cat ./sakila-db/sakila-full-dump.sql | python mysqldump-convert.py > test.sql
```

Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Nice - thanks! I have also create statements in the DUMP which should be kept ... I think we should only process INSERT INTO

Comment: I updated the script to pass-through non insert lines, handle input from pipe and add trailing semi-colons properly.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, could you mark it as accepted so that other users can see that it's an answered question? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I did not yet test it - will check it on Tuesday :-) Thank you so much for your efforts!

Comment: So I tested the script and made two really minor edits - converting a dump I did of a database with and without extended inserts lead after conversion to identical dump - perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I changed the preg (in PHP) to preg_match('/^insert into `(.*)` \([^)]*\) values (.*);/i', $line, $m); because the optimization broke when a field contained the string "values"